# ElGamal homomorphic multiplication using Bouncy Castle

Tags: java, kotlin, cryptography, bouncycastle, elgamal

Long story short: I'm in need of using `ElGamal` encryption to perform multiplication on encoded numbers.

I'm currently using `Kotlin` with `OpenJDK 1.8` and found nice provider for JCE called Bouncy Castle. It provides `ElGamal` encryption within standard `JCE API`. However, I have no idea at all how to perform multiplication on encrypted messages I get out of it.

```
Security.addProvider(BouncyCastleProvider())

val keys = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ElGamal", "BC").generateKeyPair()
val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("ElGamal/None/NoPadding", "BC")
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keys.public)
val eleven = BigInteger.valueOf(11)
val three = BigInteger.valueOf(3)
val eleven_e = cipher.doFinal(eleven.toByteArray())
val three_e = cipher.doFinal(three.toByteArray())
//Do three_e * eleven_e
```

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk it seems possible thou with RSA/ECB/NoPadding. You can toss encrypted output to BigIntegers, multiply them, mod by k and decrypt underlying byte array.

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk please look at my answer below, as I've figured out partially working solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to investigate a little bit the source code of the Bouncy Castle. It seems that contrary to what @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk says below code should be able to multiply two encoded numbers:

```
fun multiplyElGamal(num1: ByteArray, num2: ByteArray, p: BigInteger): ByteArray {
    val a1 = num1.copyOfRange(0, num1.size / 2)
    val b1 = num1.copyOfRange(num1.size / 2, num1.size)
    val a2 = num2.copyOfRange(0, num2.size / 2)
    val b2 = num2.copyOfRange(num2.size / 2, num2.size)
    return (BigInteger(1, a1) * BigInteger(1, a2) % p).toByteArray() + (BigInteger(1, b1) * BigInteger(1, b2) % p).toByteArray()
}
```

This might be only partial solution. The problem is that, part `p` of the key is 1025 bits, while parts `a` and `b` of the message got to be 1024 bit (resulting in a byte array of length 256). Modulus operation sometimes returns numbers larger than that which results in `org.bouncycastle.crypto.DataLengthException: input too large for ElGamal cipher.`

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk no worries, I would appreciate thou any suggestion about `p`

Comment: Looking over your question and answer I don't think I understand what you're trying to accomplish.